# Is a script spendable if multiple items are left on the stack?

Tags: script

Is a script spendable if the top item left on the stack evaluates to "`TRUE`", and that is the **only item left in the stack**?

In other words, is it okay for multiple items to be left on the stack?

---

For example,

A `scriptPubKey` + `scriptSig` is spenable if an `OP_1` (or anything other than `OP_0` or nothing) is left on top of the stack after the script has finished executing.

```
scriptPubKey: OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <pubkeyhash> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG
scriptSig:    <signature> <pubkey>
```

If the `<pubkey>` hashes to the `<pubkeyhash>`, and the `<signature>` corresponds the `<pubkey>`, then `OP_CHECKSIG` will end up leaving the following on the stack:

```
stack: OP_1
```

However, if you had the following `scriptPubKey` + `scriptSig`:

```
scriptPubKey: OP_2 OP_3
scriptSig:    OP_1
```

This would leave the following stack:

```
stack: OP_1 OP_2 OP_3
```

Would this evaluate to `TRUE` and mean the script is spendable?

I'm getting a `non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Extra items left on stack after execution) (code 64)` error, and I'm wondering if this is the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is the problem.

Pre-segwit there is a standardness rule in Bitcoin Core that requires a single element only on the stack after execution.

In P2WSH, this is part of the consensus rules.

The reason for this is that without such a rule it is trivial to malleate any transaction: just prefix the scriptSig with additional garbage elements, which would never be inspected by the locking script, and thus just passed through.

Comment: Thank you, makes perfect sense. I take it that my `OP_2 OP_3` scriptPubKey is unspendable unless I mine it myself?